# Gamma function results

Tags: recurrence-relations, special-functions, gamma-function

The gamma function is known to follow the below recurrence condition for all positive real numbers-

$$\Gamma\big(x+1\big)=x~\Gamma\big(x\big).~$$

Consider the function $\Gamma\big(n+\frac{1}{2}\big)$ where $n$ is a natural number. Using the recurrence described above, this could be broken down further as-

$$\Gamma\big(n+\frac{1}{2}\big)=(n-1)~\Gamma\big(n-1+\frac{1}{2}\big)=...=(n-1)!~\Gamma\big(1+\frac{1}{2}\big)=(n-1)!~\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

I was reading up online on this particular expansion, and saw formulae that didn't agree with the one that I've derived above. They state that-

$$\Gamma\big(n+\frac{1}{2}\big)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!}\sqrt{\pi}$$

What am I doing wrong in my derivation?

Comment: You have an error: the first step should be $\Gamma(n+1/2) = (n-1/2) \Gamma(n-1/2)$

Comment: Of course! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe the identity carefully- the correct version is this.
$$\Gamma\big(n+\frac{1}{2}\big)=(n-1+\frac{1}{2})~\Gamma\big(n-1+\frac{1}{2}\big)$$